# Searching diagonal in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to search diagonally in a 2D array for a connect four game.  I thought I had it figured out, but apparently I am wrong.  The first set of for loops work fine, searching right to left, diagonally.  The second set of for loops, do not work.  I thought all i had to do was switch some positive signs to negative and it work.  Eventually, I was able to get it to work partially, by changing the GRID_HEIGHT-1...BUT, I keep getting bound errors.  Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated. Also, the grid for the 2d array is 5x4.  So its really connect 3.

```
    for (int y = 0; y <= GRID_HEIGHT-3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= GRID_WIDTH-3; x++) {
            if (    
                    state[y][x] != Player.NONE && 
                    state[y][x] == state[y+1][x+1] &&
                    state[y+1][x+1] == state[y+2][x+2]
                    ) return state[y][x];
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= GRID_HEIGHT-3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= GRID_WIDTH-3; x++) {
            if (    
                    state[y][x] != Player.NONE && 
                    state[y][x] == state[y-1][x-1] &&
                    state[y-1][x-1] == state[y-1][x-2]
                    ) return state[y][x];
        }
    }


    return Player.NONE;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second set of loops, you are subtracting from the indexes, which means that the index can go below zero. You need the loop to start above zero.

```
for (int y = 2; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x = 2; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
        if (    
                state[y][x] != Player.NONE && 
                state[y][x] == state[y-1][x-1] &&
                state[y-1][x-1] == state[y-2][x-2]
                ) return state[y][x];
    }
}
```

Also, generally you should be saying (x < GRID_HEIGHT) rather than (x <= GRID_HEIGHT-1) when applicable as the second is harder to read.

Comment: I see what your saying there, still wont recognize the win though. **bands head off wall**

Comment: That's most likely due to the fact that you're checking the same diagonal twice. Try having state[y+1][x-1] and state[y+2][x-2] in one of the loops. You'll have to initialize each parameter properly.

Comment: for (int y = 2; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++) {
   for (int x = 2; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
    if ( 
      state[y][x] != Player.NONE && 
      state[y][x] == state[y+1][x-1] &&
      state[y+1][x-1] == state[y+2][x-2]
      ) return state[y][x];
   }
  }           This is what I changed and it does work, except now it gives me a bounds error at 5.  I attempted to compensate by trying to use GRID_HEIGHT-5.  Which stops the bounds error, but wont recognize the win.  [ thanks for helping ]

Comment: change it to (int y = 0; y < GRID_HEIGHT-2; y++) since you're adding to y like you did in the first loop

Comment: You awesome brother...appreciate it...now im going to go bang my head off the wall trying to figure out this AI.  .. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating from 0 to `GRID_HEIGHT-3`, iterate from `GRID_HEIGHT` downward to 3.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean there, apologies still novice coder,you mean ... for( int y =0; y=GRID_HEIGHT; y--)??